# Part(s) of speech of words and correct listing forms of "pauci, paucae, pauca"

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-identification

The Cambridge Latin Course Dictionary lists the words
*pauci, paucae, pauca*
which I assume are adjectives, and it is defined as "few, a few". I cannot find this listing in the same form on wikitionary, which instead defines it as an adjective *paucus, pauca, paucum* meaning *few, little*. Now, this in itself is strange, but then I searched up the term in Latdict (online dictionary) and it came up with this: *paucus, pauci (noun)* with a definition of *"a few"* and masculine. Latdict also supplied another noun on the same search, (this time neuter), *paucum, pauci* meaning "only a small/an indefinite number of/few things (pl.), a few words/points".

**What I want to know is whether there are multiple words, or these are the same words except with different forms, and what the correct (actual) forms of these words are.**

(Search on Latdict [here](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/pauci))

(Search on Wikitionary [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paucus#Latin))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the same words, **but in plural**.

*Paucus* is the masculine nominative singular, *pauci* either the genitive singular (when listed *paucus*, *pauci*) or nominative plural (when beginning with it).

Likewise, you have *pauca*, and *paucae*, *paucae* in the same position except feminine.

For neuter, same cases, you have *paucum*, *pauci*, and *pauca*.

The reason why *pauci*, *paucae*, *pauca* was listed separately is that it means "few" or "a few" in the plural, whereas in the singular it means "little (of)" or "few (of)". The meanings are pretty distinct, but the forms themselves are all based off a single adjectival stem.

A better dictionary tool to use is the [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=paucus&la=la#lexicon) on Perseus.